# Prisoners and guards in a queue

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 10 prisoners and 20 guards in a queue. There are 2 guards asigned to every prisoner. There is 1 guard directly behind every prisoner in a queue and another guard somewhere behind them.
Attempt: well i first thought that i would get solution like this 
$$
10\cdot 2\cdot 28\cdot 9\cdot 2\cdot 25...1\cdot 2 \cdot 1=\\ 10!2^{10}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{10}(31-3i)
$$
Or i first pick a first prisoner in 10 ways and one of his guards in 2 ways then i pick a spot for his other guard in 28 ways...problem is there aren't 28 spots for him, he cant stand on the 4th spot because 3rd spot is reserved for a prisoner

Comment: The guard of prisoner 1 that is not directy behind him, is that guard any different grom the guard of prisoner 2 that is not directly behind him? In other words, are there actually 10 pairs of guards, or just 10 gards that walk directly behind their prisoner, and 10 guards that are placed at more or less arbitrary places (with some restrictions)?

Comment: Stated another way, is the guard behind prisoner n always one of the ones that is assigned to prisoner n?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Suppose you have $2$ prisoners $X,Y$ and $4$ guards $A,B,C,D$.  Does the order $XAYBCD$ count once or twice?  You could have $\{A,C\}$ guarding $X$ and $\{B,D\}$ guarding $Y$ or have $\{A,D\}$ guarding $X$ and $\{B,C\}$ guarding $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

From the statement of your problem, I am assuming that the guards are already assigned to the prisoners (before the counting process starts).

There are $10!$ different orderings of the prisoners. Then for each prisoner one of the prisoner's two guards is chosen to stand directly behind that prisoner ($2^{10}$ ways to do this).

Let's now label the prisoners $P_1,...P_{10}$ according to their order in the line, and the directly behind guards $G_1,...,G_{10}$, and the remaining guards $g_1,...,g_{10}$.  Here specifically, the guards $G_i$ and $g_i$ are the guards of prisoner $P_i$.

So we need to place the $g_i$ guards into the line. We'll start with $g_{10}$ and work backwards. So  $g_{10}$ has only one slot available: behind $G_{10}$.  Next $g_9$ has three slots available: immediately behind $G_9$ or immediately behind $G_{10}$ or immediately behind $g_{10}$.  Similarly $g_8$ will have $5$ possible spots, and so on.

This gives a total number of arrangements of $10!\cdot 2^{10}\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot...\cdot 19$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $2$ prisoners $X,Y$ and $4$ guards $A,B,C,D$.  Does the particular order $XAYBCD$ count once or twice?  You could have $\{A,C\}$ guarding $X$ and $\{B,D\}$ guarding $Y$ or have $\{A,D\}$ guarding $X$ and $\{B,C\}$ guarding $Y$.

If your answer is to count the particular order $XAYBCD$ once then the number of orders of prisoners and guards might be:

- there are the Catalan number $C_{10} = {20 \choose 10} / 11 = 16796$ ways of positioning the indirect guards
- and $10!$ ways of ordering the prisoners,
- and $20!$ ways of ordering the guards,
- making the answer $\frac{ 20!\,20!}{10! \, 11} = 148283734702930287132672000000$ possible orderings

With $1$ prisoners and $2$ guards, this would be $\frac{ 2!\,2!}{1! \, 2} = 2$ which is obviously correct; with $2$ prisoners and $4$ guards, this would be $\frac{ 4!\,4!}{2! \, 3} = 96$ of which there are $48$ of the $XAYBCD$ type and $48$ of the $XABYCD$ type